# Infinite query parameters

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor, swagger-codegen

My application has a possibility to take infinite query parameters like

`<baseURL>/path?filter={value}&filter={value1}&filter={value2}&....filter={value999}`

how do I document this on my YAML file and use swagger codegen to create API?

I came through the following YAML template:

```
in: query
name: template_id
description: some
required: false
type: array
items:
   type: int64
```

this will give me a scope as `<baseURL>/path?filter={1,2,3...n}`
Is this the only way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`collectionFormat: multi` produces query string parameters as `filter={value}&filter={value1}&...`:

```
in: query
name: template_id
description: some
required: false
type: array
items:
   type: int64
collectionFormat: multi
```